# How to merge three lists of dictionaries into one nested dictionary using Python

Tags: python, list, algorithm, dictionary

Heads up: I learn by example, hence this question.

So, I am trying to create a nested dictionary from three (3) lists of dictionaries. The lists of dictionaries look like the following:

```
topic_list = [{"id": 1, "title": "I have no idea.", "slug": "i-have-no-idea"}, ...]
thread_list = [{"id": 1, "title": "I still have no idea.", "author_name": "me", "topic": 1}, ...]
message_list = [{"id": 1, "content": "I really have no clue what I am doing.", "author_name": "me", "thread": 1}, ...]
```

So, (I think) the end result should look something like the following:

```
nested_dictionary = [
     "topic": {
          "id": 1,
          "title": "I have no idea.",
          "slug": "i-have-no-idea",
          "threads": {
               "id": 1,
               "title": "I still have no idea.",
               "author": "me",
               "messages": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "content": "I really have no clue what I am doing.",
                    "author_name": "me"
               }
          }
     }
]
```

Basically, everything has an id. The messages are associated with the threads via the thread id and the threads are associated with the topics via the topic id.

My questions:

1. I know the format of the nested dictionary is not correct, but does it at least make sense as to what I am trying to accomplish?
2. Has anyone seen an example of this in Python?

I have literally written no code for this, but am assuming it would require nested loops that first associate all threads to the applicable topic using the topic id as a key, then associate all messages to the applicable threads using the thread id as a key.

I have looked through SO as well as performed numerous Google searches for something similar. Any suggestions and-or pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You can loop through threads, creating the nested dicts by matching messages, and then do the same by matching threads to topics? What's the issue here?

Comment: I learn by example and I cannot find an instance of what I am trying to accomplish, so I am currently stuck. I will attempt to implement your suggestion and edit the question with actual code when I have something to show.

Comment: You should mention which part confuses you more: the matching or the nesting

Comment: Both to be honest, but the matching more so. I am trying to write some code so I can hopefully give a clearer idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think that the ids your are using in your example may be the source of confusion.

> Basically, everything has an id. The messages are associated with the threads via the thread id and the threads are associated with the topics via the topic id.

While everything has an id, the thread object needs a `topic_id` to know which topic they should be nested inside of. Likewise, messages need a `thread_id` (and probably a `topic_id` too).

With this in mind, your nested dictionary would look something like:

```
nested_dictionary = {
     "topics": [
          {"id": 5247,
          "title": "I have no idea.",
          "slug": "i-have-no-idea",
          "threads": [
               {"id": 9153,
               "topic_id": 5247
               "title": "I still have no idea.",
               "author": "me",
               "messages": [
                    {"id": 1935,
                    "thread_id": 9153
                    "content": "I really have no clue what I am doing.",
                    "author_name": "me"
                    },
               ]
               },
          ]
          },
     ]
}
```

Note: I've changed the ids to make the example a little clearer.

2. Assuming the above schema is correct, your intuition of a nested for loop is correct. I would imagine such an algorithm to look something like:

```
1) Insert each topic into nested_dictionary
2) For each thread, iterate over the topics in the nested_dictionary until you find topic[id] == thread[topic_id] and insert the thread into that topic
3) For each message, iterate over the threads in the nested_dictionary until you find thread[id] == message[thread_id]
```

This represents the simplest solution. However, a better solution would change the schema to use the ids as the keys for each of the items in the nested dictionary. This would get your algorithm down to linear time complexity.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! I will try to implement and update the question accordingly.